# jquery obtain value of specific class of parent element

Tags: jquery, class, get

I am trying to obtain the value of a specific class of a parent element. My code right now can recuperate `$(this)` which points to the `td.FixListOF` cell and I would like to recuperate the value `lot_15_216297_V0_B3-102-2` of the parent class, or better said I want to recuperate the class string value that starts by `lot_` of the class. I don't care about pointing on the parent element. I need a string with the value "lot_15_216297_V0_B3-102-2"

I know that I can just grab the whole value of the class and then manipulate the data but it seems inefficient. Is there a smarter way of doing this?

```
<tr class="lot_15_216297_V0_B3-102-2 WS2 odd" _DT_RowIndex="0">
    <td class=FixListOF>
```

Thanks,

Comment: Assuming that class is always on the `tr`, you could use `$(this).closest('tr')`

Comment: or this one `$(this).closest('tr[class^="lot_"]')`

Comment: @Jai while that would work, it would rely on the `lot_` class *always* being first in the class listing, which may not be the case.

Comment: selecting the parent element wasn't what I was looking for, I cleared it up though, I just want the value of the class that starts by "lot_" in a string

Comment: "recuperate"? Is it ill? :) You cannot guarantee the order of classes in the class attribute, so you *should* split it (e.g. based on the whitespace) and iterate through all the strings.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie Dang mate, that's what I thought, alright, let's put another shrimb and the barbie ;)

Comment: Ah, stereotypes... bless em. Never gets boring :) Example below :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is to check where the element *contains* a class starting with `lot_` using the [attribute contains selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/2/) `*=` and then use a RegEx to extract the specific class.

e.g.

```
var classes = $(this).closest('[class*="lot_"]').attr('class');
alert(classes.match(/lot_\S*/));
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/34uh8ym7/2/

Comment: thanks, I looked for string manipulators and I didn't come across match!